# Is there a way to see how many cells / rows were selected when using pandas loc?

Tags: python, pandas

I am running a script that needs to highlight specific cells in a dataframe if the conditions below are met, so that I can export it to an excel spreadsheet, but I want to know how many of the cells were indeed selected and highlighted using loc in the code below. Is there a way to do this, or would a for loop be the only way to count how many were selected? If a for loop is necessary, how would I write one to parse through all rows of the dataframe, and still update the highlighting and count at the same time?

````
    a = ['P1','P2']
    b = ['P3','P4']
    p1 = ((x['priority'].str.contains('P1')) | (x['priority'].str.contains('P2'))) & (x['days_in_status'] > 7)
    p2 = ((x['priority'].str.contains('P3')) | (x['priority'].str.contains('P4'))) & (x['days_in_status'] > 14)
    p3 = (x['days_since_creation'] > 60)
    df.loc[p1,['priority','days_in_status']] = 'background-color:red'
    df.loc[p2,['priority','days_in_status']] = 'background-color:orange'
    df.loc[p3,'days_since_creation'] = 'background-color:yellow'
    df['key'] = 'color:blue;text-decoration:underline'```
````

Answer (score 0):

p1,p2,p3 are series containing booleans, meaning True or False.
Since True can also be intrepreted as a 1 you can do the following:

```
(p1+p2+p3).sum()
```

Here a short example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'test':range(1,21)})

p1 = df['test'] > 15
p2 = df['test'] < 5
p3 = df['test'] == 7

(p1+p2+p3)

# Out[181]: 
# 0      True
# 1      True
# 2      True
# 3      True
# 4     False
# 5     False
# 6      True
# 7     False
# 8     False
# 9     False
# 10    False
# 11    False
# 12    False
# 13    False
# 14    False
# 15     True
# 16     True
# 17     True
# 18     True
# 19     True
# Name: test, dtype: bool

(p1+p2+p3).sum()
# Out[182]: 10
```

Alternatively you can also just compare the dataframe before you made any changed witht he dataframe after you made changes, see this example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'test':list(range(1,10))+[1,2,3]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'test':list(range(1,10))+[3,2,1]})

df.compare(df1)

#    self other
# 9   1.0   3.0
# 11  3.0   1.0
```